# MBP won't restart or shutdown (macOS Sierra)

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, startup

I'm desperately trying to fix the issue which doesn't let my MacBook Pro restart/shutdown properly. When I click on restart or shutdown, it gets stuck when the display gets black (but still slightly on, also keyboard lights are on) forever (once let it try to restart/shutdown the whole night).

When I bought the mbp, it was El Capitan installed. I've upgraded to Sierra (now `10.12.3`) and then problems started, but I'm really not if it happened right after the upgrade or sometime later.

After booting into safe mode, restart/shutdown works.

Things I've tried so far:

- close/force quit all apps before restart/shut down
- relaunch finder before restart/shut down
- removed all apps from login items
- tried another user profile
- ran "First Aid" on Disk Utility
- restart/shut down works after booting into safe mode
- reseted SMC
- reseted NVRAM
- ran Apple Diagnostics (no issues)
- ran cache clearing commands:

`rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/*; 
rm -rf ~/Library/Saved\ Application\ State/*;
sudo rm -rf /Library/Caches/*;
sudo rm -rf /System/Library/Caches/*;
atsutil databases -removeUser;
sudo atsutil databases -remove;
sudo atsutil server -shutdown;
sudo atsutil server -ping;
sudo rm -rf /var/folders/*`

- deleted all printers
- tried shutdown -r now
- removed com.apple.finder.plist & com.apple.sidebarlists.plist
- ran a system update so permissions are going to be repaired

Answer (score -1):

Fixing permissions on my drive solved the issue.  I was able to find a solution on this [Apple Discussion thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7677685).